# $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(dx)=f(0)$ proof

Tags: measure-theory

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(dx)=f(0)$, where the delta stands for the Dirac measure. I encountered it, and I am not aware of the level of mathematical sophistication to understand this equality.

Anyway, I would like to know how this result is proven.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what the Lebesgue integral is? Do you know what the Dirac measure is? It follows directly from the definition.

Comment: I know the Lebesgue integral, however I am not aware of the Dirac measure.

Comment: Well the definition of the Dirac measure is a good place to start. The equality is trivial after that.

Comment: @ZacharySelk                 $\int_\mathbb{R}f d\delta=f\delta(\mathbb{R})=?$

Comment: What is your definition of the Dirac measure? The property in question is often taken as the definition of it.

Comment: @ZacharySelk                 $\delta(\mathbb{R})=0$, right?

Comment: $\delta(dx)$ is meaningless. Fix the typo.

Comment: @YvesDaoust                I quoted it from Wikipedia.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is a perfectly acceptable notation for the Lebesgue integral

Comment: I guess you can write it in a more general way despite the fact it was not done with all the mathematical precision it should have.

Comment: Isn't that the definition of the Dirac $\delta$?

Comment: @avs not the Dirac measure though

Comment: @SangchulLee No this is not the definition of the Dirac measure. A measure is something that takes in sets and gives out a number. This is an integral

Comment: I am not the downvoter (although I am a prolific downvoter) but please read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/can-we-be-nicer-to-downvoters

Comment: @ZacharySelk Technically you are right. I was thinking about distributional definition of Dirac mass which is then identified as a measure via representation theorem.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yup, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirac measure $\delta_{x}$ at $x$ is a Borel measure defined by
$$
\delta_x(E)=\begin{cases}
1, & \mbox{ if }x\in E\\
0, & \mbox{ if }x\notin E
\end{cases},
$$
where $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set.

Given a Borel function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
\int f\,d\delta_{x}=\int_{\{x\}}f\,d\delta_{x}+\int_{\{x\}^{c}}f\,d\delta_{x}=f(x)\delta_{x}(\{x\})+0=f(x).
$$

Answer (score 4):

Note:

$$\delta(A)=\begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } 0 \in A\\0 \text{ else}\end{cases}$$

So $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(dx)=f(0) \delta(\{0\})=f(0)$$

Comment: How do you get the $f(0)$?

Comment: @PedroGomes Define the Lebesgue integral

Comment: I got it! Thanks! So it means the dirac measue operates only on {0}, right?

Comment: $\delta(A)=\delta(0)=1$ if $0\in A$?

Comment: @PedroGomes Its support is just $0$, if that's what you mean

Comment: @PedroGomes If $\delta$ is a measure, $\delta(0)$ means no sense. But $\delta(A)=\delta(\{0\})=1$ if $0\in A$

Comment: @zacharyselk Zack, just curious ... What was your former user name?  Avid?

Comment: @Mark yeah avid19

Comment: Good to see you're back.

Comment: @Mark and you too Dr MV :) Your answers are always wonderful. I've had nothing but pleasant interactions with you. Thanks for all you do for this site.

Comment: @zacharyselk Wow!  Thank you.  That made my week.  And may I return the compliment.